# Query to do indepth search for a regex is not working properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having one query to do indepth search for a regex in mongoDB. I'm using JS function inside the query like this -

```
db.collection.find(
        {$where: function() {
        function  deepIterate(obj, value) {
        var new_value = new RegExp("^"+value, "i");
        for (var field in obj) {
            if (obj[field] == new_value){
                return true;
            }
            var found = false;
            if ( typeof obj[field] === 'object' ) {
                found = deepIterate(obj[field], new_value)
                if (found) { return true; }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    return deepIterate(this, "[A-Ba-b0-9]*60.51[A-Ba-b0-9]*")
}}
)
```

It doesn't return any values, output is `Fetched 0 record(s) in 4ms`. But I'm having one string in my database - `192.108.60.51`. That record is not getting returned.
Help!!!

Comment: I think you're missing a `.` between the `*` and the `60`, because your character class doesn't include a `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution -

```
db.collection.find({$where: function() {
        function  deepIterate(obj, value) {
        new_value = new RegExp(value, 'i');
        for (var field in obj) {
            if (new_value.test(obj[field])){
                return true;
            }
            var found = false;
            if ( typeof obj[field] === 'object' ) {
                found = deepIterate(obj[field], new_value)
                if (found) { return true; }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    return deepIterate(this, "[A-Ba-b0-9]*60.51[A-Ba-b0-9]*")
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your regex pattern into `deepIterate(this, "(([1-9]?\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\\d)\\.){3}([1-9]?\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\\d)$")` this regex is for find string that is an Ip-Address. You can't find any record because your regex pattern not match with your record in database

Comment: Hi, Actually this format is coming like this only from a python file. I'm using pymongo. I want to search for the regex that I'm having. Also I checked the regex that you provided, it is not working.

Comment: @roguepanda You should change `(obj[field] == new_value)` into  `new_value.test(obj[field])` it's right syntax from regex

Comment: Tried this, It is returning all the records. Let me explain, I'm having two records in collection. In one record there is value 192.108.60.51. for that I was searching as regex of 60.51(mentioned in question). I've made sure that other record won't match with this regex value but still both records are getting returned.